# lodash groupBy all keys most efficient way

Tags: javascript, grouping, lodash

I'm trying to find an efficient way to aggregate all items of a collection.

For example, what would be with Lodash the most efficient way to group this collection of objects by each of its keys (in depth) if the values are not sub-objects or arrays?

```
let input = [{
    food: {
        fruits: {
            apples: 2,
            bananas: 3,
            peaches: 'square',
            citrus: [100,200,300] 
        },
        meat: {
            beef: 1000,
            chicken: 2000
        }
    }
},{
    food: {
        fruits: {
            apples: 4,
            bananas: 5,
            peaches: 'triangle',
            citrus: [101,201,301] 
        },
        meat: {
            beef: 1001,
            chicken: 2001
        }
    }
}];

let output = {
    food: {
        fruits: {
            apples: [2,4],
            bananas: [3,5],
            peaches: ['square', 'triangle'],
            citrus: [[100,101],[200,201],[300,301]]
        },
        meat: {
            beef: [1000, 1001],
            chicken: [2000, 2001]
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem that there is a function that does it in the API, and I was wondering if there is a way to do that in one pass without iterating several times on the initial collection.

Comment: The output `citrus` has 3 arrays, not 2, is that deliberate?

Comment: As with all of these types of questions, you need to look at `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Comment: Also, the first item has `peach` and the second item has `peaches`. Similar problem with `citrus` and `critus`, and `beaf` is probably supposed to be `beef`. Spelling matters in programming

Comment: yep sorry, I edited my example directly in here, I should have done it in IDE. it is fixed, and for citrus, it should be an array of array assuming all items of the collection are homogenous in property size etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs#mergeWith) as follows:

```
const output = _.mergeWith({}, ...input, (t, s) => {
  if (!_.isObject(s)) return t ? [...t, s] : [s]
});
```

```js
const input = [{
  food: {
    fruits: {
      apples: 2,
      bananas: 3,
      peaches: 'square',
      citrus: [100, 200, 300]
    },
    meat: {
      beef: 1000,
      chicken: 2000
    }
  }
}, {
  food: {
    fruits: {
      apples: 4,
      bananas: 5,
      peaches: 'triangle',
      citrus: [101, 201, 301]
    },
    meat: {
      beef: 1001,
      chicken: 2001
    }
  }
}];

const output = _.mergeWith({}, ...input, (t, s) => {
  if (!_.isObject(s)) return t ? [...t, s] : [s]
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This returns exactly your desired output (after correcting the input inconsistencies):

```
{
  "food": {
    "fruits": {
      "apples": [2, 4],
      "bananas": [3, 5],
      "peaches": ["square", "triangle"],
      "citrus": [[100, 101], [200, 201], [300, 301]]
    },
    "meat": {
      "beef": [1000, 1001],
      "chicken": [2000, 2001]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed it in the docs, probably the same reason I made so much inconsistency typos: I should sleep more :).
Thank you for your answer it is exactly what I was looking for.